# Equivalent of SQL "limit" clause in Datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

Title sort of says it all, but say I have a simple query as follows:

```
(q '[:find ?c ?n :where [?c :my-thing/its-attribute ?n]]
   (d/db conn))
```

against a schema like

```
[{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/db)
  :db/ident :my-thing/its-attribute
  :db/valueType :db.type/string
  :db/doc "My thing's attribute"
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}]
```

If the query matches everything (say, 100M entries), the returned results will be large.  If I just want a few of them, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: You can specify a limit with a [pull expression](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html#limit-expressions).

Comment: @BenKamphaus that looks promising.  Because `pull` needs an entity argument, does that mean I need to establish some hierarchy where all the things I want to query (and limit) are attributes of some other thing (the last argument to `pull`)?  Currently I have only the one kind of attribute in my minimal schema.

Comment: Just use take (or drop/take if you need to start somehwere in the middle)

Comment: @GuillermoWinkler that works fine as long as your query doesn't return a massive collection -- if I understand correctly the query result is not lazy.

Comment: @JohnJ limit in pull is for limiting returned values for cardinality many attributes. Read this a little too quickly. For lazy access against a simple query, [datoms](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/datoms) targeted against the correct index is probably a better fit than query.

Answer (score 10):

Two random names using rand (duplicates tolerated) and sample (only distinct)

```
(d/q '[:find [(rand 2 ?name) (sample 2 ?name)]
       :where [_ :artist/name ?name]]
     db)
```

This example came from the [day-of-datomic](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/98c1d9b2967ad5317e83b6da50f7c0e5c3d7a207/tutorial/query.clj) github repo.

Comment: This is really the simplest and most idiomatic answer and should be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

For the simple cases of "all attribute and value pairs, sorted", using take with [`seek-datoms`](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/seek-datoms) is your best option. The following example uses the [mbrainz](https://github.com/Datomic/mbrainz-sample) sample database:

```
(def conn (d/connect "datomic:sql://mbrainz-1968-1973?jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/datomic?user=datomic&password=datomic"))

(->> (d/seek-datoms (d/db conn) :avet :artist/sortName "Bea")
     (take 20))
```

and returns:

`(#datom[17592186050196 81 "Beach Boys, The" 13194139539089 true]
 #datom[17592186047857 81 "Beatles, The" 13194139536749 true]
 #datom[17592186048553 81 "Beau Brummels, The" 13194139537425 true]
 #datom[17592186049043 81 "Beaver & Krause" 13194139537919 true]
 #datom[17592186046205 81 "Beaver, Paul" 13194139535085 true]
 #datom[17592186046692 81 "Beck, Bogert & Appice" 13194139535579 true]
 #datom[17592186046886 81 "Beck, Jeff" 13194139535761 true]
 #datom[17592186047111 81 "Beck, Jeff Group" 13194139535995 true]
 #datom[17592186046486 81 "Bedford, David" 13194139535371 true]
 #datom[17592186046992 81 "Bee Gees" 13194139535865 true]
 #datom[17592186045876 81 "Beethoven, Ludwig van" 13194139534747 true]
 #datom[17592186048427 81 "Beggars Opera" 13194139537321 true]
 #datom[17592186047091 81 "Beginning of the End, The" 13194139535969 true]
 #datom[17592186045945 81 "Belafonte, Harry" 13194139534825 true]
 #datom[17592186047485 81 "Bell, Archie & Drells, The" 13194139536359 true]
 #datom[17592186045915 81 "Bell, Carey" 13194139534799 true]
 #datom[17592186046324 81 "Bell, Vinnie" 13194139535215 true]
 #datom[17592186047164 81 "Bell, William" 13194139536047 true]
 #datom[17592186047652 81 "Belle, Marie-Paule" 13194139536541 true]
 #datom[17592186046496 81 "Bellou, Sotiria" 13194139535371 true])`

Of course, you can map a fn that prettifies the output or adds more attributes, etc. such as in this example:

```
(let [db (d/db conn)]
  (->> (d/seek-datoms db :avet :artist/sortName "Bea")
       (take 20)
       (map #(merge {:artist/name (:v %)
                     :artist/type (-> (d/pull db [{:artist/type [:db/ident]}] (:e %))
                                      :artist/type
                                      :db/ident)}))))
```

Which returns:

`({:artist/name "Beach Boys, The" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beatles, The" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beau Brummels, The" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beaver & Krause" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beaver, Paul" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Beck, Bogert & Appice" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beck, Jeff" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Beck, Jeff Group" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Bedford, David" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Bee Gees" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beethoven, Ludwig van" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Beggars Opera" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Beginning of the End, The" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Belafonte, Harry" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Bell, Archie & Drells, The" :artist/type :artist.type/group}
 {:artist/name "Bell, Carey" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Bell, Vinnie" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Bell, William" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Belle, Marie-Paule" :artist/type :artist.type/person}
 {:artist/name "Bellou, Sotiria" :artist/type :artist.type/person})`

**Note**: to use `seek-datoms` or `datoms` with `:avet`, the attribute in question must be indexed.

Comment: Sounds interesting, will give that a try next time I get my hands dirty with Datomic.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is sort of a compilation of that of @adamneilson and the comments on the original question. I was trying to accomplish the same thing as the OP, but wasn't quite able to find my answer here, so hopefully this'll help someone.

My use case was to pull 100k records with pagination. It was absolutely not feasible to simply use `take`/`drop`, as it took a really long time (tens of seconds).

My workaround was to first fetch the entity ids required, do `take`/`drop` on that collection, then map over them with `entity`. Here's my final code:

```
(defn eid->entity
  [eid]
  (into {} (d/touch (d/entity (d/db (get-conn)) eid))))

(defn find-eids
  [attr value limit offset]
  (let [query '[:find ?eid
                :in $ ?attr ?value
                :where [?eid ?attr ?value]]
        db (d/db (get-conn))
        result (drop offset (sort (d/q query db attr value)))]
    (map first (take limit result))))

(map eid->entity (find-eids :attr-name "value" 10 10)
```

This feels super wrong to my SQL-trained brain, but I think it's the datomic way. And it's not terribly slow - about 500ms for 100k records, which is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of a SQL "limit" clause can be achieved with the key :limit when using a query-map.

```
 (d/q {:query '[:find ?c ?n :where [?c :my-thing/its-attribute ?n]] 
       :offset 1
       :limit 10
       :args [(d/db conn)]})
```

You can read more about this in the datomic client api documentation:

https://docs.datomic.com/client-api/datomic.client.api.html

or about the query-map syntax:

https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html#timeout

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `:limit` and `:offset` are available only in `datomic.client.api`, not in `datomic.api`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `get-some` ?

From: http://docs.datomic.com/query.html

> get-some
>
> The get-some function takes a database, entity, and one or more
>   cardinality-one attributes, returning a tuple of the entity id and
>   value for the first attribute possessed by the entity.

```
[(get-some $ ?person :person/customer-id :person/email) ?identifier]
```

-- Edit to respond to comment --

You could also try making a query that selects entities below a certain number.

```
user> (defn example-take-query [n]
        (into '[:find ?e :where [?e :age ?a]]
              [[`(~'> ~n ~'?e)]]))
#'user/example-take-query
user> (example-take-query 3)
[:find ?e :where [?e :age ?a] [(> 3 ?e)]]
user> (example-take-query 10)
[:find ?e :where [?e :age ?a] [(> 10 ?e)]]
```

Comment: Like Clojure's `some` core function, it seems this only returns one matching tuple, rather than N.

Comment: That is not what I want either -- it's a workaround (at best), and what I want is the correct *idiom.*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need a while back put together a clojure *MySql* method of `LIMIT` for a collection:

```
(defmacro limit 
"Pagination mimicking the MySql LIMIT" 
([coll start-from quantity]
    `(take ~quantity (drop ~start-from ~coll)))
([coll quantity]
    `(limit ~coll 0 ~quantity)))
```

Simple example usage on the repl:

```
user=>  (defmacro limit 
  #_=>     "Pagination mimicking the MySql LIMIT" 
  #_=>     ([coll start-from quantity]
  #_=>     `(take ~quantity (drop ~start-from ~coll)))
  #_=>     ([coll quantity]
  #_=>         `(limit ~coll 0 ~quantity)))
#'user/limit
user=> (def hundred (take 100 (iterate inc 0))) ;; define a collection
#'user/hundred
user=> (limit hundred 25) ;; get the first 25 from the collection
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24)
user=> (limit hundred 25 25) ;; get the next 25
(25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49)
```

Not sure it exactly answers your question but it might be of some use.

Comment: That macro will work just as well (or better) as a plain function.