# How to find only one record from query in datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm doing a query on datomic using datomic.api like the following:

```
(d/q
  '[:find [(pull ?a [*]) ...]
    :in $ ?title
    :where
    [?a :movie/title ?title]]
 db title)
```

This query is returning almost the expected value, but as an array, like this:

`[ {:db/id 17592186045442, :movie/title "Test", :movie/year 1984, :movie/director #:db{:id 17592186045439 }} ]`

I want this query to return only the first match, and not all the results. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. Why not just (first ...) on the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of SQL "limit" clause in Datomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162566/equivalent-of-sql-limit-clause-in-datomic)

Comment: @alex314159 Because `d/q` can return an arbitrary amount of items, they might not even fit in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the replies!

@alex314159 , I'm already using the (first ...) solution, but I wanted a direct query to do that, as there is no scenario where I will use more than one result.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov , thank you for the link, it was not exactly what I needed, but was a good place to look for possible answers. I will post the way I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documented in the official [Datomic documentation](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#find-specifications):

> Find Spec
>
> - :find ?a ?b relation (Collection of Lists)
> - :find [?a …]    collection (Collection)
> - :find [?a ?b]   single tuple    (List)
> - :find ?a .  single scalar (Scalar Value)

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I was even looking at the documentation to study...

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my specific case. The real issue was that I was not understanding the datomic query correctly.

```
[:find [(pull ?a [*]) ...]
```

This part is telling datomic to retrieve more than one result.
I changed the query to the following one:

```
(d/q
  '[:find (pull ?a [*]) .
    :in $ ?title
    :where
    [?a :movie/title ?title]]
 db title)
```

And it worked!
The key thing was to remove the "[" after :find keyword, and switch the "..." for only ".".

If this doesn't work for you, look on the link that @EugenePakhomov posted on the comments: [Equivalent of SQL "limit" clause in Datomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162566/equivalent-of-sql-limit-clause-in-datomic)